# WP Events Manager Pro Plugin Live Payment Failing

Tags: wordpress, authorize.net

I have setup a wordpress instance where people can register for online courses, I am wiring this up with authorize.net, when I test the account in sandbox mode it works fine. When I enter the live credentials and change the mode to live the payment breaks and it says booking cannot be created gateway authorize.aim

can anyone help with this

Answer (score 0):

What is error or debug output that you are getting from Authorize.net's gateway?  Do you see the transaction in your Authorize.net merchant interface?

From my experience, there are generally 3 areas where this type of issue can occur:

1. **API Problem** - You need to ensure that you are able to submit transactions properly to the API and that they show up in the merchant interface (either as a decline or approval, etc).  If not, you probably need to regenerate your API User / Transaction key and check your delimiter and encapsulation characters.
2. **Not Parsing Response** - It's possible that Authorize.net is receiving your transaction but your application isn't parsing the response properly.  Make sure the delimiter and encapsulation character match what you're using in the Authorize.net settings so that your app can parse the response properly.
3. **Processor Problem** - If the API is working fine and you can see the transactions in the Authorize.net merchant interface but are still getting declines, you may need to contact your processor / merchant provider to ensure things are active on their end.  Also, you need to be using a real credit card -- test card numbers won't work once you switch to live mode.

Lastly, a good pro-tip is to just attempt your transaction using the virtual terminal.  If it works there, then you know all is good with your processor configuration and settings.  If not, you've got a problem with your processor configuration and need to reach out to your merchant provider.